# Wavemaker using MouseZoomAndPan

Tags: charts, zooming, panning, wavemaker

In wavemaker a got an app that display charts with dojo charting, some charts have a lot
data so the chart is compressed so i look around and found that we could add zooming and panning, found an example on the web link:http://informatik.fh-brandenburg.de/~porebskk/dojo.html

i look at the source code and it looks like i only had to add this to my code

dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.MouseZoomAndPan");

and then call it before rendering the chart

new dojox.charting.action2d.MouseZoomAndPan(chart, "default");

My problem is when i had this to my source code
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.MouseZoomAndPan");

and run the app i get "page Main as error" and my application does not work anymore

if i do this then my application comesback to life
//dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.MouseZoomAndPan");

i create a new application and i only had this on top of the main page and get
the error again
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.MouseZoomAndPan");

in the wavemaker debugger i get "error parsing pages/Main/Main.js"

Answer (score 0):

I am using AMD style but this may help you.  I was able to find the missing piece with your link.

Dojo toolkit had some [slightly incorrect code here (MouseZoomAndPan section)](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/charting.html?codekitCB=411945722.255561), but it will give you the code I have below and is why I have commented out code after MouseZoomAndPan(...);

```
define(["dojox/charting/themes/Claro", "dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default"
    , "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", "dojox/charting/action2d/MouseZoomAndPan"],
function (claro, Chart, Default, Lines, MouseZoomAndPan) {
    return {
        createZoomableChart: function () {
            "use strict";
            var chart = new Chart("mouseZoom");
            chart.addAxis("x", { type: Default, enableCache: true })
                .addAxis("y", { vertical: true })
                .addPlot("default", { type: Lines, enableCache: true })
                .addSeries("Series A", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 7, 5]);
            var mzap = new MouseZoomAndPan(chart, "default");//, { axis: "x", "none" });
            chart.render();
        },
        init: function() {
            this.createZoomableChart();
        }
    };
});
```